# How do you create a new keystore in Corda?

Tags: keystore, corda

As per the title, in Corda, how do you create a new keystore as referenced here - https://docs.corda.net/permissioning.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the class **X509KeyStore**

Passing a password into the constructor will create an empty keystore for you.

Alternatively, the function fromFile in the same class can be used to create a keystore if one doesn't already exist.

The test class **X509NameConstraintsTest** is a good place to see this in action along with the "Test save to keystore" test within CompositeKeyTests.kt.